# Error 0x80070519 reading file: revision level is unknown

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, data-recovery, deduplication

I have mounted a dedup volume in Windows Server 2012 R2. When I try to copy a file from the volume to another I get the error `0x80070519 revision level is unknown`

The volume seems to be healthy otherwise:

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-DedupMetadata

```
Volume                         : B:
VolumeId                       : \\?\Volume{63545545-e9fc-11e1-be6d-c86000c32999}\
StoreId                        : {5ADD827E-A0EF-430E-920C-72198453D560}
DataChunkCount                 : 5203495
DataContainerCount             : 351
DataChunkAverageSize           : 70.33 KB
DataChunkMedianSize            : 0 B
DataStoreUncompactedFreespace  : 0 B
StreamMapChunkCount            : 140519
StreamMapContainerCount        : 5
StreamMapAverageDataChunkCount :
StreamMapMedianDataChunkCount  :
StreamMapMaxDataChunkCount     :
HotspotChunkCount              : 43
HotspotContainerCount          : 1
HotspotMedianReferenceCount    :
CorruptionLogEntryCount        : 0
TotalChunkStoreSize            : 349.88 GB



PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-dedupstatus

FreeSpace    SavedSpace   OptimizedFiles     InPolicyFiles      Volume
---------    ----------   --------------     -------------      ------
106.02 GB    68.42 GB     140317             140317             B:


PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-dedupvolume

Enabled            UsageType          SavedSpace           SavingsRate          Volume
-------            ---------          ----------           -----------          ------
True               Default            68.42 GB             15 %                 B:
```

Is there anything I can do to save the data and read the files?

Comment: I've managed to save my files by mounting the drive on the original machine and enabling dedup on the volume there. But if anyone wants to shed light on the original question, it could be helpful to someone else in the future. There's no help for this error anywhere on the internet that I could find.

Comment: I am having this issue now. I saw the problem might be the os version but afaik the os version is the same. Sam machine too, just a different installation.